# Chrome and Chrome Canary auto-complete feature

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I have Chrome and Chrome Canary installed on my machine. In Chrome when I browse a website that has a form, as soon as I enter the first character, the `auto-complete` shows up and I can select my previously type data. But in Chrome Canary even if I type the data, the next time nothing shows up.

Is there any option somewhere for this? I'm not able to find anything. Not to mention, I'm not talking about form `auto-fill`. This is just a drop-down while you're typing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming chrome canary is basically chrome with a few mods in which case you're looking for  chrome://settings/ maybe chromecanary://settings, then look for more options and autofill is in there.

It might be the form you are trying to fill has it disabled autofill or canary might clear it cache everytime you close so it does not remember last data you entered

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.